# mat1 dim 1 must match mat2 dim 0 - PyTorch

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network

Im new to PyTorch and I keep getting the error `mat1 dim1 must match mat1 dim0`

this is my code for the network

```
class Net(Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(Net, self).__init__()
        
        self.cnn_layers = Sequential(
            Conv1d(4,4,kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=1),
            BatchNorm1d(4),
            ReLU(inplace=True),
            MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2,stride=1),
        )
        
        self.linear_layers = Sequential(
            Linear(8267*4,2)
        )
        
    def forward(self, x):
        print(x.shape)
        x = self.cnn_layers(x)
        print(x.shape)
        x = self.linear_layers(x)
        return x
```

and where the print statements are:

```
torch.Size([8267, 4, 1])
torch.Size([8267, 4, 1])
```

Any help/advice?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming `8267` is your batch size. The output of your CNN is `8267x4x1`. So you first need to flatten `dim=1` and `dim=2` into a single dimension to get a shape `8267x4`. Then the following layer (dense) will require `4` neurons.

```
self.cnn_layers = Sequential(
    Conv1d(4, 4, kernel_size=2, stride=1, padding=1),
    BatchNorm1d(4),
    ReLU(inplace=True),
    MaxPool1d(kernel_size=2, stride=1))
    
self.linear_layers = Sequential(
    Flatten(),
    Linear(4, 2))
```